# Error when recovering SagePay orphaned transaction

Tags: magento-1.9, error, payment-methods, sagepay

Lately, I have been experiencing problems when trying to recover some SagePay orphan transactions. This doesn't apply to all as some of the "Recover" with no problem.

When I click on "`Orphan Transaction List`" which appears at the top information bar in Magento admin panel:
[image]

Then find the transaction I need to recover and click on "`Recover`" in action:
[image]

I get `The requested Payment Method is not available.` error:
[image]

Been searching and I figure out what's going on...

Also, not sure if it is relevant, when creating a order in the admin and make the total amount to £0.00, I also get the same error `The requested Payment Method is not available` even tho the payment method is not required. I have checked the configuration and `Zero Subtotal Checkout` is enabled.

Could anyone help or at least direct me?

I use `Sage Pay Suite PRO v4.1.7 by ebizmarts` and `Magento ver. 1.9.2.4`

SagePay:

[image]

Comment: Hello there, have you found a solution yet ?

Comment: Hi there, I didn't, I have contacted the SagePay but they don't support this anymore... If you do find the answer, please post it here too! I gave up on this :D

Comment: Have you tried to contact eBizmarts as they actually built this module, and because this is no free edition they should at least explain what is going on. I'm trying to do similar things, sometimes I have orphaned orders then while recovery it says "unknown Payment method" or something like this. Sometimes I'm able to recover it manually but sometimes even if I change all the required things in database directly it still won't work.

Comment: ALso you should update your module to Sage Pay Suite PRO v4.2.4  as in this version there is  a quiet few updates and fixes. My configuration is quiet similar to yours, Magento 1.9.2.3 and Sage Pay Suite PRO v4.2.4

Comment: I have contacted Ebizmarts and explained my issue, but they turned around and said that they don't support this module anymore... I'm currently building Magento 2 version of this site so will migrate all the modules over, hopefully bug free :)

Comment: What do you mean "they not support this version anymore" so it is not SagePay Suite PRO but CE edition ? If so, then yes, right they do not. I thought you are using paid version not Community Edition. ;) I used to used CE edition but because there was a lot of problems with and they not supported it anymore changed it to paid version .... and I still have the same problems .... :P CRAP!

Comment: It is Sage Pay Suite PRO, I have contacted them number of times now, they always had a excuse to why not actually answer my question or give me some advice. I tried the Ebizmarts forum too, buy my post got closed for the reason of [not supporting this module anymore]... By the temporary fix I'm recreating the orders, the ones that I can't recover and building a new site in the meantime.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72493/discussion-between-robert-a-and-bare-feet).

Comment: Hi @RobertA. any luck with this?

Comment: Hello @Bare Feet, nope, still looking for some ways how to.

Comment: Actually I'm in contact with Federico Peregerino (ebizmarts developer/web technician) which trying to help me with this issue.

Comment: I have just sketched an email too, and waiting for reply. I just thought yours went a bit further now :) Thanks for info!

Comment: Any luck with this issue Bare Feet ?

Comment: Nothing.... Still trying to figure out what's going on... I tend to have like 7 orphaned transactions a week that can't be recovered.... What about you?

Comment: omg 7!?, all I have is 1 a fortnight or less, but 7 .... OMG!
Still working on it, spoken to ebizmarts about module modification. Suggested to add a form in case if you can't automatically recover to set all the required/missing details but what they told me is "Yes, good idea but unfortunately this modification may take some time" so I do not expect it within next .... few months :P 
However, after my previous actions they fix some other issues :P
You said the version you currently have is 4.1.x ?
Can you send me a screenshot of your module info/about page ?

Comment: Posted another question on Magento Stack-exchange, maybe someone already know how to manually recover orders. I managed to do it once changing data directly in database but I can't remember now what I've done also I've had some issues even I changed data for other orders so the method I found is not reliable.

Comment: Yes, this is a lot... Our business and customer services and accounts have a lot of problems due to this issue... It takes a lot of effort and unsatisfied customers due to it as I have to refund them loosing about £500 in sales a week! Have a look at the updated question for a screenshot.

Comment: I'm running this on a 1.9 store taking over 100 orders a day, and rarely if ever get an orphaned transaction. I set sagepay pro to deferred payment, then capture on success page - this fixed a lot of issues in the early days.

Comment: Hello Ricky O.M. could you explain please what you've done a little bit wider ?